# Accuracy of reverse geocoded addresses

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

Currently im reverse geocoding a lng and lat into an address. This works fine. Although the problem is the location it returns does not include the street name or street number but the marker i place is right on the exact location im in.

its for a mobile app i have tried it in many locations always with the same result.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because of 2 reasons. 
1. Either Google map is not containing any data for  street name or street number.
2. Or U are not declaring the proper attribute for  "street name" or "street number" with a proper type of geocode (other then Default) .

Comment: *slaps head* its a stupid mistake in the end i was getting the second element in the results array....